# Python 3.8 from mock import Mock E ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mock'

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

So I am trying to use **from mock import Mock**
to mock some of my methods in my unit tests. I do:
But I am getting:
Traceback:

```
../../_tool/Python/3.8.10/x64/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    from mock import Mock
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mock'
```

I tried:

pip install mock
It's still not working.

and with pytest-mock and mock

it is working on some machines.

Comment: install it by `python3.8 -m pip install mock`

Answer (score 1):

you can use inbuilt unittest module to work with mock

```
 from unittest.mock import Mock
```

Comment: I must use  from mock import Mock so can not use from unittest import mock.